# Flutter: Show animation or progress indicator unitil accessing elements from API

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting data from API in my weather app. I want to display loading animation until I access elements from API. Right now it shows null in text widget and null image error for few seconds before getting data from API. After few seconds it displays data correctly.

Here is the Data class in which I'm getting data from API

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DataClass {
  double? long;
  double? lat;
  Future<void> getcurrentlocation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
      lat = position.latitude;
      long = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  String? discription,
      temperature,
      wind,
      pressure,
      humidity,
      main,
      countryname,
      area;
  var iconurl;

  Future<void> getdata() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$long&appid=5174d985695c2502f2a5307e7cbc6036');
    var response = await http.get(url);

    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    discription = data["weather"][0]['description'];
    main = data["weather"][0]['main'];
    iconurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
        data["weather"][0]['icon'] +
        ".png";

    Map main_data = data["main"];
    temperature = main_data["temp"].toString();
    // print("$temperature");
    humidity = main_data["humidity"].toString();
    pressure = main_data["pressure"].toString();

    Map wind_data = data["wind"];
    wind = wind_data["speed"].toString();

    Map sys_data = data["sys"];
    countryname = sys_data["country"];

    area = data["name"];
  }
}
```

This code display item from Data class in my UI

```
import 'package:api_practice/worker/data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:api_practice/worker/data.dart';

class WeatherHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeatherHomeState createState() => _WeatherHomeState();
}

class _WeatherHomeState extends State<WeatherHome> {
  TextEditingController searchcont = TextEditingController();
  DataClass datainstace = DataClass();

    

  void data() async {
    await datainstace.getcurrentlocation();
    await datainstace.getdata();
    print(datainstace.area);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    data();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .999,
          color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 60, 15, 15),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search City",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontSize: 17),
                        focusColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 30,
                    right: 26,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.search_rounded,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                ("${datainstace.area}"),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Image.network(
                "${datainstace.iconurl}",
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot 1 : [image: null_error_for_few_seconds]
Screenshot2 : [image: DisplayDataCorrctly]

Comment: you can try with futureBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case better go with FutureBuilder

```
body: FutureBuilder(
    future: datainstace.getdata(),
    builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ); // loader
      } else {
        if (dataSnapshot.error != null) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('An error occured'),
          ); // error
        } else {
          return Column(..., Text(
            ("${datainstace.area}"),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Image.network(
            "${datainstace.iconurl}",
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),)
          // UI element that consumes data from Future
        }
      }
    },
  ),
```

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html